# Autorun.inf cannot deal with the sub-folders with space in their folder name?

Tags: windows, installation, autorun, dvd

I am trying to use an autorun.inf to run my executable file under a sub-folder with space in its folder name. Like this:

```
H:\
    autorun.inf
    FOLDER NAME 1
        file.exe
    FOLDER NAME 2
        some other stuffs
```

If there's no space in the folder name, it works well. But if there are some, it's not work for me.

Is this a restrict? or I am doing something wrong?

My autorun.inf:

```
[autorun]
open=FOLDER NAME 1\Setup.exe
icon=FOLDER NAME 1\Setup.exe
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With some trials I have found that pairs of double quotes are needed. Sounds strange though.

open=""FOLDER NAME 1\Setup.exe""

Answer (score 6):

Expanding on from Sanjay's answer of using two sets of quotes, like

```
open=""FOLDER NAME 1\Setup.exe""
```

If you want your icon from the folder, you need to put a single set of quotes around the whole line. E.g.

```
icon="FOLDER NAME 1\Setup.exe,0"
```

Answer (score 2):

My uninformed guess: use quotes.

```
[autorun]
open="FOLDER NAME 1\Setup.exe"
icon="FOLDER NAME 1\Setup.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to doing as Thomas suggests and using quotes, you can also use the short/"DOS" style names.  Which are the first 6 letters of the name followed by a tilde (~) and then a number.  So "FOLDER NAME 1" would usually become "FOLDER~1".

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
open=.\FOLDER NAME 1\Setup.exe
```

edit: works for icon, NOT for open command...a bit strange!